# Close JFrame from a JButton process remain alive

Tags: java, swing, jvm, jframe

I have a class developed with windowbuilderpro that i want to close also from a JButton further than with the standard X button on the window, so here the example of the class :

```
public class MainWindow {

public JFrame frame;

public MainWindow() {
    initialize();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  }

public void show() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Show the main Frame
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

When i close the window from the X button the window close correctly and the process terminate.

When i close instead from a JButton that have this listener :

```
mntmExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               //Close the application main form
               frame.setVisible(false);
               frame.dispose();
            }
        });
```

the frame window close correctly but the process remain alive ... Why ?

[image: Process Alive]

As you can see there is an AWT-Shutdown thread that start and terminate continuously, How can i achieve the same behaviour of the X button that close also the application process ?

**Notes :**

System.exit(0); is not suitable because it terminate the application also if there are another background running thread and i don't want that . The MainWindow class should close and release it's resource, the same behaviour that have closing the application with the X button that close the MainWindow instance but if there are background thread running it doesn't kill they but wait until they finished their work...

**Enviroment :**

- JDK 7
- Eclipse 3.7.1

Comment: Something I should have said before:- For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  In an SSCCE, a loose timer would have been obvious.  And since I am mentioning code, could you choose one of the logical styles of indenting code, and stick to it for future posts?  It took me longer to reformat and make sense of that code than it took to turn it into working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what you really needed, that looks like that you create new JFrame again an again, don't do that, create JFrame once and re-use this Container

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); // do nothing

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE); // same as setVisible(false)
```

then for visibily you can only to call `frame.setVisible(true);`

for more Confortable is override [WindowListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html), then you can control some Events

Comment: I've created frame instance only once, why if i close the form with the X button on the window title i get the right behaviour and instead if i close the frame calling dispose i get i different behaviour ?

Comment: implements WindowListener create one void that share Action from JButton with Events from WindowListener, hmmm implements SystemTry with JPopumMenu, add JMenuItem with JFrame#setVisible(true);

Answer (score 2):

All threads in this code stop when either the `x` button or the `Exit` button are activated.  Are you getting different behavior?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainWindow {

    public JFrame frame;
    JButton mntmExit = new JButton("Exit");

    public MainWindow() {
        frame = new JFrame("Close Me!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        mntmExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Close the application main form
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });
        frame.add(mntmExit);
        frame.pack();
        show();
    }

    public void show() {
        //Show the main Frame
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
                mw.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah when i try to close the frame from Exit button the thread remain alive as you can see in the screenshot image, instead if i close the window with the X button on the window the application close correctly, because no other thread are active. I want to achieve the same behaviour with the close button that i've created ... I'm using JDK 7 .

Comment: Try it in JDK 6.  If it shows different behavior in (the as yet very buggy) Java 7, it is probably a ..bug.

Comment: Just ran this program with build 1.7.0-b147 and build 1.6.0_25-b06, both on x64 and they close fine. Just thought I'd throw in some support that it might be a version issue.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I left i timer Running and this caused the issue, it is necessary to call timer.cancel() to let application close correclt, however i've implemented the solution that mKorbel suggested. Thanks !

Comment: @pimaster.  Thanks for your result.  The OP might throw some property (e.g. version) printing into the code & use it as the basis for a bug report.

Answer (score -1):

Just add one line:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Syste.exit(0); close the application also if there is a running background process in another thread and that kill my background thread !! I don't want do that !

Comment: When I answered this question, aleroot didn`t talk about background process, and has edited his question after my answer.